# When using command pallet of VSCode, I can not use Back space in editors in VSCode

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I was searching a thing in command pallet such as CTRL+Sift+P in VSCode.
Next, I needed to write programs in editors in VSCode.  While wirting codes in a editor, I found a typo.

So I wanted to delete a charactor by using Back space.  But, I could not delte the charactor in only the VSCode Editers. I can remove any charactors or numbers, while using any other editors such as pycharm, and, other editors. If I hit the Back space, the cursor moves to command pallet.
I checked short cut of the preferece of VSCode.  But, I could not find any short cut of the Back space.

I use Win10, and VSCode version is V1.70.

I searched google.  But, I have not found any answers.

Please help

I googled in relation to VSCode of the problems.
But, I have not found any hint or any solution.

I would like to use Back space of my key board.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try the follwing:

```
use "keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode" in your settings and restart VS Code
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
But. the cause was different.
I wrote the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that I registered short cut key which was SQL.
If I hit backspace twice, automatically the cursor moved the command pallet.

So, I registered short cut key to a completely different character.
Then, I got the solution.

Thanks